# EmEditorでマクロファイルごとにホットキーを割り当てることはできますでしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
マクロファイルごとにホットキーを割り当てることは出来ますでしょうか？

たとえば、
A.jsee

B.jsee

C.jsee

これらを複数すぐに動作させたい場合に、各マクロにショートカットキーを割り当ててボタンを押しただけで、いろんなマクロを動作させられるようにしたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

設定のプロパティの [キーボード] ページで、`分類` に `マイ マクロ` を選択して、`コマンド` に割り当てたいマクロを選択して、好きなショートカットを割り当てることができます。[image: EmEditor - 設定のプロパティ - キーボード]

Comment: お世話になっております。回答ありがとうございます。EmEditorは至れり尽くせりです。とてつもない便利さです。